# change value to percentage of row in R

Tags: r, percentage

this is my data

```
  A B C
A 9 1 0 
B 2 2 2
C 3 3 3
```

I want to get percentage of each row

my expect data is

```
     A    B    C
A  0.9  0.1    0 
B 0.33 0.33 0.33
C 0.33 0.33 0.33
```

I made my data with 'dcast' and there is column name on A,B and C.
so actually my real data is

```
  Name    A    B    C
1    A  0.9  0.1    0 
2    B 0.33 0.33 0.33
3    C 0.33 0.33 0.33
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Seems a fair case for

```
df/rowSums(df)
#           A         B         C
# A 0.9000000 0.1000000 0.0000000
# B 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.3333333
# C 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.3333333
```

If you don't want so many digits after the dot set `options(digits = 2)` or use `print(df/rowSums(df), digits = 2)` or use `round`

```
round(df/rowSums(df), 2)
#      A    B    C
# A 0.90 0.10 0.00
# B 0.33 0.33 0.33
# C 0.33 0.33 0.33
```

Or as suggested by @akrun

```
round(prop.table(as.matrix(df1),1),2)
```

Comment: You can also include `round(prop.table(as.matrix(df1),1),2)` this option

Comment: @akrun why did you delete your solution?

Comment: problem with data structure. how to take column name off?

Comment: `df[-1]/rowSums(df[-1])` probably